# SwiftUI view task and async function

Tags: swift, concurrency

I'm getting a warning with this code and I don't understand how to fix it. I'm curious to know how to pass a function into the `task` modifier.

```
private func placeholderRHSView(for client: AppClient) -> some View {
    Color.clear
        .frame(width: 290, height: 290)
        .task(load(client)) // Warning: Converting non-sendable function value to '@Sendable () async -> Void' may introduce data races
}

private func load(_ client: AppClient) -> () -> Void {
    return {
        Task {
            do {
                let apps = try await client.recent()
            } catch {}
        }
    }
}
```

How should I re-structure this code to make it thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is having that floating `Task {/*code*/}` that isn't thread safe and should not be used without a very good reason and precautions that mimic `.task` lifecycle behavior.

Now to get a function that can be used directly in `.task` we have to mimic the signature

```
func task(priority: TaskPriority = .userInitiated, _ action: @escaping () async -> Void) -> some View
```

The `action` is `() async -> Void` so the function should return that exact type. You are missing the `async` part.

You also have to add `@Sendable` which we only know about from warnings

```
private func load(_ client: AppClient) -> (@Sendable () async -> Void) {
```

`()` means that this will be a closure/function so the body will be enclosed with `return {/*async code here*/}`

```
private func load(_ client: AppClient) -> (@Sendable () async -> Void) {
   return {
        do {
            let apps = try await client.recent()
            print(apps)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Now your `View` will work as expected.

```
private func placeholderRHSView(for client: AppClient) -> some View {
    Color.clear
        .frame(width: 290, height: 290)
        .task(load(client))
}
```

I created a little mock `AppClient` to make this complie.

```
struct AppClient{
    func recent() async throws -> String{
        return "recent"
    }
}
```